# After deploying CakePHP3 application to Ubuntu server, all assets return 404 response

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

When I deployed my CakePHP3 application to the Ubuntu server into `var/www/html/{project_name}` directory using git push, all assets such as images, css files, javascripts, etc...from the webroot folder are not loading. They return 404 response.

[image]

This is my `.htaccess` file inside `webroot` directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$    /    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /$1    [L]
   AllowOverride All
</IfModule>
```

And this is my `.htaccess` inside root directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    ReWriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure modrewrite is working? What do the log files say?

Comment: Is mod rewrite enabled on the server?

Comment: @FrankerZ where can I view the log?

Comment: Check where your accesslog and errorlog are writing to (In your apache config file)

Comment: @mcgowan.b I just now used `a2enmod rewrite` command and now my page doesn't load at all, it says `404 Not Found The requested URL /webroot/index.php was not found on this server.` Btw, on same server, cakephp2 project runs just fine.

Comment: What is the path of your webroot folder?

Comment: @error2007s `/var/www/html/{project_name}/webroot`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running `composer install` from the root project directory.

Note that if your server uses PHP7 rather than PHP5 for your app, you should install universal packages rather than dropped PHP5 packages.